# Qual a aplicação do conceito de ponteiros para funções?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Gostaria de um exemplo prático para a utilização de ponteiro para função bem como uma função tendo como um dos parâmetros um ponteiro que aponta para uma função; não é necessário mostrar algum código, gostaria de uma visão para um projeto maior mesmo

Comment: Nao existe projetos especificos, ponteiros é essencial para a programação em C, é como saber quanto é 1+1, nao serve para nenhum projeto em especifico, mas ajuda a resolver problemas.

Comment: mas por quê usar esse conceito? qual a vantagem?

Comment: Imagine que tem variaveis e que quer mudar o valor de 3 variaveis numa funçao, como consegue fazer isso? Ou são variaveis globais ou so por apontadores.
É um exemplo muito simples de uma aplicação